# HAProxy check says server is down when it is up

Tags: linux, glassfish, haproxy

I am trying to setup 2 Glassfish servers in a load balanced configuration using UCARP and HAProxy

**Server1** has 2 IPs x.x.x.17 and x.x.x.18

HAProxy is listening on only x.x.x.18 and Glassfish listening on only x.x.x.17 running with the following configuration...

```
global

maxconn 4096
debug
user haproxy
group haproxy

defaults

mode http
retries 3
option redispatch

listen wms x.x.x.18:8080
source x.x.x.18
option httpchk
balance leastconn
server Server1 x.x.x.17:8080 check inter 2000 fastinter 500 fall 2 weight 50
server Server2 x.x.x.19:8080 check inter 2000 fastinter 500 fall 2 weight 50
```

**Server2** with 1 IP x.x.x.19 is running Glassfish

Even though I can manually wget the page from x.x.x.17:8080 and receive a 200 OK response, HAProxy says Server1 is DOWN and doesn't direct any requests to it.  I can't find any reason why.

Here is an excerpt from the Server1 access log with the checks...

```
"x.x.x.18" "NULL-AUTH-USER" "14/Jan/2010:14:44:23 +0000" "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.0" 200 0
"x.x.x.18" "NULL-AUTH-USER" "14/Jan/2010:14:44:23 +0000" "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.0" 200 0
"x.x.x.18" "NULL-AUTH-USER" "14/Jan/2010:14:44:23 +0000" "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.0" 200 0
"x.x.x.18" "NULL-AUTH-USER" "14/Jan/2010:14:44:29 +0000" "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.0" 200 0
"x.x.x.18" "NULL-AUTH-USER" "14/Jan/2010:14:44:29 +0000" "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.0" 200 0
```

Here is an excerpt from the Server2 access log with the checks...

```
"x.x.x.18" "NULL-AUTH-USER" "14/Jan/2010:14:58:25 +0000" "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.0" 200 0
"x.x.x.18" "NULL-AUTH-USER" "14/Jan/2010:14:58:25 +0000" "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.0" 200 0
"x.x.x.18" "NULL-AUTH-USER" "14/Jan/2010:14:58:31 +0000" "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.0" 200 0
"x.x.x.18" "NULL-AUTH-USER" "14/Jan/2010:14:58:31 +0000" "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.0" 200 0
```

If I remove the httpchk option then Server1 checks as UP, however this is not a permanent solution because we need it to fail over properly if the response really fails.

Any ideas?

(HAProxy is v1.3.22)

Addn:  I just tried adding server3 x.x.x.13 running Glassfish but on Windows and that also says down when it is up and accessible from the proxy machine.

Addn2: After installing v1.4 of haproxy to get error codes, the error is Layer7 invalid response info: "HTTP/1.1 ".  When we retrieve the page manually both the UP and DOWN server return HTTP/1.1 200 OK as the first line.

So after running wireshark to see what is going on.  On the glassfish server which works (and all the other webservers I've checked) the response HTTP/1.1 200 OK all comes in the first packet.  On the glassfish servers that don't work the response comes in 3 packets of HTTP/1.1 then 200 then OK.

So any idea why HAProxy is not dealing with multiple packets or how to configure glassfish not to split it? (maxKeepAliveRequests=1 already)

Comment: So, just to confirm, server2 is being fed requests from haproxy, whilst server1 isn't?  Also, what does the haproxy web interface say about all this?

Comment: yes in the stats page it says server2 status is DOWN and no pages being fed to it

Comment: It should not matter how many packets it takes.  From HAProxy, it should be a TCP stream, not a packet level.

Comment: It shouldn't matter, but perhaps this is triggering a bug in HAProxy?  I can't say for certain, I'm not too familiar with HAProxy.  However, if you have the packet traces that seem to show haproxy doing the wrong thing, sending them to the upstream author might not be a bad next move.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is that Glassfish in the latest versions splits the response into multiple packets.

I posted on the haproxy [mailing list](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/#tact) and had a remarkably quick response.

Krzysztof Oledzki confirmed that haproxy assumes that the response will all be contained within the the first packet as that is the behavior of most known web servers.  He built a patch with a quick and dirty fix which is available in the mailing list archives if you search for Glassfish and can be applied to the beta or latest stable version 1.3.22

I also tried to find out why Glassfish has started to behave this way but without paid support I got nowhere.  If anyone can answer that, the bounty is still open.

Comment: Just for completeness, version 1.4.4 is able to handle multi-packet responses.

Answer (score 1):

run tcpdump and capture the checks and their responses to each server.  compare the results from server1 to the results from server2.

if it works on server1 but not on server2, or server3, then server1 must be returning something different.  If they aren't returning something different, then something is wrong with haproxy or your haproxy configuration.

Comment: Justin's right here, you gotta compare exactly what its seeing.  My bet is glassfish is responding slightly differently on localhost than it is to remote clients.

Comment: Kind of pointing out the obvious but thanks anyway.  I tried this and have updated the question with the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in additional arguments into httpchk...

ie.

```
option httpchk HEAD /test.php HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: well I had to try option httpchk HEAD /test.php HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ xxxxxxxx:8080 but it made no difference

Comment: I guess another step, rule out the obvious, configs the same on both glass fish? Same versions?  Can you post configurations?  How about the packet captures?

Comment: +1 This solved it for me. I was using `httpd` (busybox) server and for some reason without the additional arguments it was reported as `down`